# Get NOT IN on a one to many relationship using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table `LookUpRole` as so

```
LookUpRoleId | RoleName
```

another table called `UserAccounts` as so

```
UserAccountId | FirstName | LastName
```

another table called `UserRole` as so

```
UserRoleId | LookUpRoleId | UserAccountId
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
using (var db = new AMSEntities())
{
    var roleList = (from lur in db.LookUpRoles
        join ur in db.UserRoles on lur.LookUpRoleId equals ur.LookupRoleId
        join ua in db.UserAccounts on ur.UserId equals ua.UserAccountId
        where ua.UserAccountId == accountId
        select new UserRole()
        {
            LookupRoleId = lur.LookUpRoleId,
            UserId = ua.UserAccountId
        }).ToList();

    var lackingRoles = db.UserRoles.Where(x => !roleList.Contains(x.LookupRoleId)).ToList();
}
```

A UserAccountId may have multiple LookUpRoleId. I just want to get the list of RoleName or LookUpRoleId that is not related to the UserAccountId yet. For example; UserAccountId of 1 has LookUpRoleId of 1 and 2. I need to get the RoleName of LookUpRoleId 3 and 4 using LINQ. Thank you.

Comment: Your Question is hard to understand. Doesn't a simple where condition suffice in your case?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your linq effort. Should have a join between the tables (unless EF with navigation properties and then should also be specified in question)

Comment: Sorry Gilad. I wasn't able to include my feeble try.

Comment: @Ibanez1700 - that is ok but notice for next time - that is the reason for the downvotes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join from the roles to the user-roles. Then query those that are null:

```
var result = from role in db.LookUpRoles
             join ur in db.UserRole 
             on { role.LookUpRoleId, accountId } equals new  {ur.LookUpRoleId, ur.UserAccountId } into j
             from ur in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where ur == null
             select role.RoleName;
```

You can also do:

```
var result = from role in db.LookUpRoles
             where !db.UserRole.Any(ur => ur.UserAccountId == accountId && ur.LookUpRoleId == role.LookUpRoleId)
             select role.Name;
```

Comment: I used the second option. It's easier to understand. Besides, I can't make the first option to work =). Thank you.

Comment: @Ibanez1700 - you are welcome :) I agree but it's worth checking the generated sql to compare performances